# How to add xib subviews with dynamic height to UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, xib, ios-autolayout

It should be easy to do and it's very easy in android(with LinearLayout) but I can't figure out how to do it in ios.

I have UIView into which I want to add some dynamic height subviews. Subview is loaded from xib file and contains 2 UILabels with dynamic height.

```
class Subview: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var desc: UILabel!


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.commonInit()
    }

    fileprivate func commonInit() {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Subview", owner: self, options: nil)
        addSubview(contentView)
        self.contentView.frame = self.bounds
        self.contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    }

}
```

and subview is added like this

```
var containerView: UIView

func setupView() {

    let subview1 = Subview()
    subview1.title = "Some title"
    subview1.desc = "Some very long description"

    self.containerView.addSubview(subview1)

}
```

Issue is that in this case, subview is not displayed.
If I add

```
subview1.frame = CGSize(width: self.bounds.width, height: 100)
```

subview is displayed but height 100 is not correct

If I try to calculate subview size

```
let measuredSize = subview1.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: self.bounds.width, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)))
```

measured width and size is 0.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here? Thanks!

Edit: This is my subview xib file with constraints
[image]

Comment: have you tried to use the constructor to set the size ? `let subview1 = Subview(wantedSize)`

Comment: But I don't know wantedSize. Size (height) should be dynamic based on content

Comment: I would find a way to calc it before creating the view but you can also try to use `subview1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` right after its creation. I'm wondering if there is no constraints being generated and then preventing frame to be resized

Comment: Use auto-layout and constraints... much more flexible than trying to calculate rects and sizes.

Comment: my subview xib file contains constraints but it's not sized properly when it's added into containerView.
I tried to set subview1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false and subview is now visible but it's out of containerView and not multile

Comment: you need to set the position inside the containerView which is given by leading ,trailing and top

Comment: plus if you want to wrap element you need to hook it's leading&trailing in the xib file or give it a width , if lbl don't forget .lines = 0

Comment: height constraint >= is useless

Comment: you need to set bottom of desc to superView , .lines property to the lbls to 0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can easily accomplish this by

1- hooking the constraints properly in the xib file from top to bottom

2- `theView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`

3- set leading , trailing , top constraints ( No height ) , for eample this is a simple xib with one label 
[image]

When adding it to self.view by

```
let vv = (Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("repairView", owner: self, options: nil))?[0] as! repairView;

vv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

vv.aedlb.text = "dsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsvvvvdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsvvvvdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsvvvvdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsvvvvdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjdsdsjhdsjhdsjhsdhjdsjhesisbeudjbdsjbdsjds"

view.addSubview(vv)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

    vv.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 20),
    vv.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
    vv.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),

    ])
```

The result
[image]

Comment: Thanks. It seems that NSLayoutConstraint.activate did a trick.

Comment: yes , because according to it the subview will know it's position & width hence wrapping accordingly to fit the dynamic size content